# Neural network algorithm doesn't work

Tags: r

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(readr) 
library(stringr)
library(neuralnet)

train <- read.delim("../input/train.tsv")

test <- read.delim("../input/test.tsv")

category <- str_split_fixed(train$category_name,"/",3)

category_test <- str_split_fixed(test$category_name,"/",3)

train$category_a <- category[,1]

test$category_a <- category_test[,1]

train$category_b <- category[,2]

test$category_b <- category_test[,2]

train$category_c <- category[,3]

test$category_c <- category_test[,3]


train = train[,!(names(train) %in% c("category_name"))]

train = train[,!(names(train) %in% c("item_description"))]

train = train[,!(names(train) %in% c("name"))]

test = test[,!(names(test) %in% c("category_name"))]
test = test[,!(names(test) %in% c("item_description"))]
test = test[,!(names(test) %in% c("name"))]

train$brand_name <- as.numeric(train$brand_name)
train$category_a <- as.numeric(factor(train$category_a))
train$category_b <- as.numeric(factor(train$category_b))
train$category_c <- as.numeric(factor(train$category_c))

test$brand_name <- as.numeric(test$brand_name)

test$category_a <- as.numeric(factor(test$category_a))

test$category_b <- as.numeric(factor(test$category_b))

test$category_c <- as.numeric(factor(test$category_c))


max = apply(train , 2 , max)

min = apply(train, 2 , min)

max_test = apply(test , 2 , max)

min_test = apply(test, 2 , min)

scaled = as.data.frame(scale(train, center = min, scale = max - min))

scaled_test = as.data.frame(scale(test, center = min_test, scale = max_test - min_test))

set.seed(2)
results = neuralnet(price ~ item_condition_id + shipping + category_a + category_b , scaled, hidden = 3,linear.output = T)
#results <- lm(item_condition_id + price ~ shipping + category_a + category_b , data=train)

pre <- compute(results,scaled_test)

solution <- data.frame(test_id = test$test_id, price = pre)

write.csv(solution, file = 'sample_submission.csv', row.names = F)
```

Comment: I've put code formatting around this. But that's a lot of code to read. You need to explain more than "doesn't work" - first what problem are you trying to solve - what does your data look like, what are you trying to predict? Then what exactly is going wrong when you run your code?

Comment: I need to predict the price of a product from 7 features, the problem is that my algorithm exceeds one hour of execution, I need to reducte this!

Comment: So the code works just fine, but it is too slow for you? I suggest [edit] the question to include what you have just commented. Change title too, because "doesn't work" is not useful information to someone trying to answer the question. Also worth including: Number of examples in your data set.  Maybe someone who knows the NN libraries for R can suggest a faster option . . .